which values can take resource_type attribute from aws_launch_template / tag_specifications
Looking for a solution for another topic, I'm wondering what values the resource_type field in the tag_specifications section of an aws_launch_template can take.
resource "aws_launch_template" "foo" {
  name = "foo"

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  image_id = "ami-test"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "test"

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name = "test"
    }
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "volume"

    tags = {
      Name = "test"
    }
  }
}

This code has been extracted from kichik's answer from stack overflow and I gather it can take instance / volume.
There are other possible values?

So, diving into the nitty-gritty of AWS launch templates, huh? Great choice! Let's unravel this mystery together.
Alright, so when it comes to the resource_type attribute in the tag_specifications section of an aws_launch_template, it's all about defining what kind of resource you want to apply those tags to. In your example snippet, you've got two instances of tag_specifications, each with a different resource_type. The resource_type here specifies whether you're tagging an instance or a volume. So, in your case, you can use "instance" or "volume" for the resource_type depending on whether you want to tag instances or volumes created from this launch template. Pretty straightforward, right? Just remember, choose wisely depending on what you want to tag, whether it's instances or volumes. Happy tagging!
